# Torque on two nearby points of a free-moving solid

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, torque

Consider the 2D problem of a uniform square rigid body on which I pull one corner with a constant force $\vec{F}$ and push the neighbouring corner with the force $-\vec{F}$. The body is free to move in the plane. The total force applied to the body is zero and according to Newton's first law, the center of mass (i.e. the center of the square) should not move, and the resulting torque should make it spin around the center. However, this seems to fail in the way I visualize the following experiment: the pull and push forces are transferred to the corners via two rods that freely rotate around their points of attachment. In this case, I expect a displacement of the center of mass to accompany the rotation.

i) Which hypothesis fails or which force did I forget to account for?

ii) How to understand this in the case where the forces are applied on a circle at any two points but across a diameter?

Comment: It's a bit tricky to talk about this without a diagram, but if I imagine correctly what you're trying to put across, consider that if the freely rotating rods are indeed acting on neighboring corners, *and hence rotating in the same direction* they will each apply two components of force on the square body: one in opposite directions, which is the one you mentioned and hence that cancels, but another one each in the same direction and hence will not be cancelled but rather reinforced. So there seems to be a net force on the center of mass due to the rotation being in the same direction.

Comment: @Amit Thanks for the suggestion. I think you're indeed very close. I considered that the forces kept their initial direction during the motion, which made the problem much less obvious than what you described with their simultaneous rotation with the square.

Comment: So the thought experiment fails because they are additional forces present to control the evolution of the direction of (or the distance between) the forces during the rotation. If they are introduced, it becomes possible to adjust the rods and maintain the motion around the centre of mass alone.

Comment: Yep. The thing is: if the contact between the rod and the square is at an angle, it is clear why there would be an additional component. But if the initial contact is such that there is no angle between the rod and the square, it means that there is some segment of the rod now overlapping the edge of the square. hence, in the next instant there will be an angle, due to the rotation :) So in both cases, such a rod is not able to provide a force in only one direction.

Comment: And indeed there is never any degenerate case with an "instantaneous" force since the force needs to work over a finite distance to inject kinetic energy into the system. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You may be able to adjust the rods if you change the setup: I think that perhaps if they will be applied on the diagonal rather than neighboring corners, you may be able to pull off what you want to... they will still move in the same direction, but if I imagine it correctly the forces will cancel on both axes. It requires writing down of course to be certain :)

Comment: You're welcome, and welcome to the site :)